# webrtc renegotiate failed when send new offer to c++ native api

Tags: javascript, c++, webrtc

I am developing a web page that captures camera frame to server via webrtc. 
In the server side, we build an application which written by c++ that do webrtc peerconnection.

Any thing was good when receive stream from same camera, but when we try to switch camera on the web page and renegotiate sdp, the c++ side throws error and shows "SetRemoteDescription failed: Called with an SDP without SDES crypto and DTLS disabled locally".

The following js code is what we do when switch camera

```
current_stream.stop();
myPeerconnection.removeStream(current_stream);
peerConnectionCreateOffer();
```

Please correct if we have any error or misunderstanding, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `MediaConstraintsInterface::kEnableDtlsSrtp` to the list of constraints when creating the peerConnection (myPeerconnection in you case).

The constrains is the second argument to `PeerConnectionFactoryInterface::CreatePeerConnection()`